# how to run matlab script in mac terminal

Tags: matlab, terminal

I search for this and got some answer involving sudo, I am a beginner to linux and curious how to do it in terminal,

say my file is in Desktop/hw
matlab is installed in application
could give me a detailed commands instructions?

Thanks

Comment: MATLAB has a `-r` command line option. The name of the script should follow. However, there are already numerous answers to your question on the internet, e.g. https://beagle.whoi.edu/redmine/projects/ibt/wiki/Calling_Matlab_from_the_Linux_command-line

Comment: hi, I am a beginner, even do not understand exact meaning of some commands. Do we need to add path like APPLICATION/MATLAB_2013b.app ?or just matlab -r hw.m?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just check that on my MacOS machine. Depending on where you installed your MATLAB, but

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/Contents/MacOS/MATLAB_maci64 -nodisplay
```

worked for my case.

Comment: thanks a lot, how to make /Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/Contents/MacOS/MATLAB_maci64 simply as matlab to make life easier?

Comment: in your ~/.bashrc file, add `alias matlab="/Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/Contents/MacOS/MATLAB_maci64"`

Comment: and vote/accept my answer if it is helpful!

Comment: I am new here how to increase your reputation?

Comment: just "accept" my answer. there should be a checkmark right by voting arrows.

Comment: it requires 15 reputations, sorry, I only have 1....